# do other tasks when a context menu is shown (hence WM_ENTERIDLE is sent)

Tags: winapi, contextmenu, python-idle

In firefox, after users right click at a tab item and the context menu is shown, if he moves the mouse to another tab item, the "another" tab item will be highlighted. But in IE, the "another" tab item won't be highlighted, and the same as in many WIN32 applications with tab control.

I think this is because the `WM_ENTERIDLE` message is sent. For `dialog box`, we have `DS_NOIDLEMSG` style to suppress the `WM_ENTERIDLE` message.

Do we have similar style for context menu? Or could the app continue to execute tasks even the context menu is shown?

Comment: I think it's more likely that is just not the active window or the mouse input has been captured.

Comment: Thanks, Deanna. Do you know a way to avoid "the mouse input is not captured" when a context menu is shown?

Comment: Are you asking a question about Python's IDE Idle?  (which I probably can answer), or is this a mis-tagging?